# python turning an input field of floats into a properly separated list of numbers

Tags: python, html, forms, input

I'm working on a flask app where I need the users to input a list of numbers which will be floats. I have a current method which looks like:

```
times = request.form.get("FORMNAME")

        if not times:
            return "Error: Please enter a list of numbers"

        #print(times)
        timelist = []
        #print(times)
        #print(list(times))
        for i in range(0,len(times)):
            if times[i] != ",":
                timelist.append(int(times[i]))
```

Now this works most of the time, but I feel like its sloppy and inefficient, and when I use decimals it throws everything off. I believe I need to use the `map()` function, but I'm a bit confused on the usage and not sure how to apply it to my code, though I suspect it would work. Simply put, I want to take my input from the HTML form, and turn it into a list of values. IE my input would be something like 1.23,2.34,3.45 and it returns me a list such as [1,23,2.34,3.45].

Using `list()` turns every individual character into a list element, and turning it into a string does me no good. What's the best way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Python does have a method for splitting a string without the need for a loop: `map(float, times.split(','))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding slightly on what GWW said, you can use:

```
timelist = list(map(float, times.split(',')))
```

Comment: I tried this but when I try to iterate through the list it iterates through every character, I need it to iterate through every float number in the list.

Comment: I ran the following code:

    `times = '1.23,2.34,3.45'

    timelist = list(map(float, times.split(',')))

    print(timelist)`

and got [1.23, 2.34, 3.45] as a result. I guess that depends on the times input being a string though.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting there, I'm not sure how to get that right!